# Using fetch in chrome extension sends null origin header

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, fetch-api

When sending cross origin requests using the fetch API the `origin` request header is being set to null instead of the `chrome://xxxxx` that I was expecting. Using fetch in both the background.js context as well as the injected iframe context result in the same behavior.

When I use XMLHttpRequest instead it sends the expected origin header.

Is there some control in the manifest.json (or something else) that is preventing fetch from behaving as expected? My understanding is that the `origin` header is "protected", so trying to set it manually obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Related: https://crbug.com/661827

Comment: Sounds like a bug: https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/444. Normal XMLHttpRequest does send the correct origin header

Comment: @Mark
Do u know if it ever sends a referer header?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed the same issue. My workaround is to use XMLHttpRequest instead of fetch like what OP mentioned. With XHR, it does send origin as `chrome://**extension-id**` but not referer header. No referer header with [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) too.

In case somebody wonders how to use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).
The following code snippet taken from [MDN XMLHttpRequest readState document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log('UNSENT', xhr.readyState); // readyState will be 0

xhr.open('GET', '/api', true);
console.log('OPENED', xhr.readyState); // readyState will be 1

xhr.onprogress = function () {
    console.log('LOADING', xhr.readyState); // readyState will be 3
};

xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log('DONE', xhr.readyState); // readyState will be 4
};

xhr.send(null);
```

If you prefer to use a promise, you can use a promise to wrap XMLHttpRequest. You can check out [this article on how to turn XMLHttpRequest into promise](https://www.language-diary.com/2018/12/make-xmlhttprequest-into-promise-xhr.html) for more information.

```
function xhr(params) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = '';

    xhr.open('POST', url + params);

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.responseType = '';

    xhr.onerror = function() {
      reject(new Error('error'));
    };

    xhr.onload = function() {
      // do something with response
      let res = xhr.response;
      resolve(res);
    };

    // send request
    body = JSON.stringify({ params });
    xhr.send(body);
  })
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with manifest V3, using fetch() is now mandatory in background.js :-(

Answer (score 0):

There should be some way to make fetch send the Origin header when executed from the extension background worker (with manifest V3)...
What about using specific **referrerPolicy**? (https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/fetch-api/fetch-referrer-policy.html)

Comment: In fact the Origin is sent when the method is POST, but not with GET.
From https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#origin-header :
The `Origin` header is a version of the `Referer` [sic] header that does not reveal a path. It is used for all HTTP fetches whose request’s response tainting is "cors", as well as those where request’s method is neither `GET` nor `HEAD`. Due to compatibility constraints it is not included in all fetches.